# The Sieve of Alice- Number theory Riddle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, puzzle, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to prove the result for a problem which I am unable to do so!
The answer is simply $\frac{N}{2}$ when N is even and $\frac{N}{2}+1$ when $N$ is odd. But I do not see why?? Can you give me a formal proof? And a line  of thinking for such problems?

> The Sieve of Alice, formally defined by the
>   following procedure, which determines the Sieve of Alice up to a given
>   limit $N$.
>
> 1. Create a list of consecutive integers from $N$ to $2$ $\left(N, N-1, N-2,\cdots, 3, 2\right)$. All of those $N-1$ numbers are initially unmarked.
> 2. Initially, let $P = N$, and leave this number unmarked.
> 3. Mark all the proper divisors of $P$ (i.e. $P$ remains unmarked).
> 4. Find the largest unmarked number from $2$ to $P – 1$, and now let $P$ equal this number.
> 5. If there were no more unmarked numbers in the list, stop. Otherwise, repeat from step 3.
>
> Unfortunately, Alice has not found an useful application for it's
>   Sieve. But she still wants to know,
>    for a given limit $N$, how many integers will remain unmarked?

Comment: You should look for a pattern in the specific numbers that are left unmarked (or marked).

Comment: Hint. The best line of thinking is to compute some small examples. Work this out by hand for $N=12$ and $N=15$ and you'll see which half of the numbers remain. That should be a clue for a formal proof. (I'm pretty sure someone will jump in with a full solution before you have time to do this.)

Comment: Pattern wise what I thought was if N is a prime then I cannot mark any number!! And I have to move to P-1 i.e is a recurrence ! 
But I couldn't think of any method for composite numbers..
And yeah thanks for the way I will try it always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ is unmarked if and only if $a>\frac{n}{2}$.

Proof: suppose $a$ has a multiple in interval $[2,n]$. consider the largest multiple of $a$ in the interval $[2,n]$, this number must also be unmarked, but if it is unmarked then $P$ took its value at some point in time, when this happened we marked $a$. On the other hand it is clear the numbers larger than $\frac{n}{2}$ where never marked because $P$ never took the value of a multiple of that number.

Therefore there if $n=2k+1$ the $k+1$ numbers $k+1,k+2\dots 2k+1$ are unmarked and if $n=2k$ the $k$ numbers $k+1,k+2\dots 2k$. So $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$

Comment: Someone with a *smiling cat* avatar answered a question about the Sieve of *Alice*? Curiouser and curiouser ...